# Identity theorem for power series

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I spent a lot of time but I can't understand why $B$ is open? Can anyone show it rigorously, please?

Comment: Take a sequence in $B$ that converges to some point. Is this point in $B$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x\in B$, i.e., $x$ is not a limit point of $E$, then by Rudin's definition, we have $N_\epsilon'(x)\cap E=\emptyset $ for some $\epsilon>0$. Then $N_\epsilon(x)\subseteq B$: For $x$ this is clear, for $y\ne x$ let $\delta=\min\{|x-y|,\epsilon-|y-x|\}$ and note that $N_\delta'(y)\subseteq N_\epsilon'(x)$.

Comment: Can you help with this, please? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577296/brief-moment-from-theorem-8-5-on-pma-rudin