# Brief moment from theorem 8.5 on PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

He want to prove that $A$ is open. He take any $x_0\in A$ and showed that exists $\varepsilon:=R-|x_0|$ such that for any $x\in N_{\varepsilon}(x_0)$ we have $f(x)=0$. $A$ is the set of all limit point of $E$ in $S$.

How he conclude that $N_{\varepsilon}(x_0)\subset A$?

Can anyone explain this brief moment please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He proved that $N_{\epsilon}(x_0)\subseteq E$ and $A$ the set of all limit points of $E$ in $S=(-R,R)$. Hence $N_{\epsilon}(x_0)\subseteq A$.

Let $p\in N_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ then $p\in (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ and for any $\delta>0$ we have that $N'_{\delta}(p)\cap N_{\epsilon}(x_0)\neq \varnothing$ $\Rightarrow$ $N'_{\delta}(p)\cap E\neq \varnothing$. Then $p$ is a limit point of $E$ in $S$, i.e. $p\in A$. Thus $N_{\epsilon}(x_0)\subseteq A$.

Comment: By $N_{\delta}'(p)$, do you mean $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$? I'm confused about the prime symbol in $N_{\delta}'(p)$ :-)

Comment: @sunny, I guess it means the deleted neighborhood of $p$.